# accessing java two-dimensional vector from scala

Tags: java, scala, vector, multidimensional-array

Here's my case: 
I created a table with DefaultTableModel

So when I use getDataVector I get a two-dimensional java.util.Vector.

When I use toSeq or any other converter I get something like

```
Buffer([5.0, 1.0, 50.0], [10.0, 1.5, 40.0], [2.0, 1.5, 90.0], [1.0, 1.0, 100.0], [6.0, 3.0, 100.0], [16.0, 3.5, 50.0])
```

The inner objects are returned as java.lang.Object (AnyRef in scala), and not as arrays

How can I convert them or access their contents?

Here is the code to test

```
 import collection.mutable.{Buffer, ArrayBuffer}
 import javax.swing.table._
 import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

 var data = Array(
             Array("5.0", "1.0", "50.0"),
             Array("10.0", "1.5", "40.0"),
             Array("2.0", "1.5", "90.0"),
             Array("1.0", "1.0", "100.0"),
             Array("6.0", "3.0", "100.0"),
             Array("16.0", "3.5", "50.0"))


 val names = Array("K¹", "K²", "K³")

 val m = new DefaultTableModel(data.asInstanceOf[Array[Array[AnyRef]]], names.asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]])

 val t = m.getDataVector.toSeq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an older interface in Java, so it returns a pre-generic `Vector` (i.e. a `Vector[_]`).  There are a variety of ways you could deal with this, but one is:

```
val jv = m.getDataVector.asInstanceOf[java.util.Vector[java.util.Vector[AnyRef]]]
val sv = jv.map(_.toSeq)
```

to first explicitly specify what the return type ought to be, and then convert it into Scala collections.  If you prefer to convert to immutable collections, you can

```
val sv = Vector() ++ jv.map(Vector() ++ _)
```

among other things.  (These are now Scala immutable vectors, not java.util.Vectors.)

If you want to mutate the vectors that were returned, just use jv as-is, and rely upon the implicit conversions to do the work for you.

---

Edit: added a couple other ways to get immutable collections (possible, but I wouldn't say that they're better):

```
val sv = List(jv.map(v => List(v: _*)): _*)
val sv = Vector.tabulate(jv.length,jv(0).length)((i,j) => jv(i)(j))
```

Note that the second only works if the table is nonempty and rectangular.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you share some other ways too